# Django : How to distinct by DateTimeField with ignoring the second / millisecond difference

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

In Django,  i have a model that look like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   ...
   created = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
   ...
```

And I try to query like:

```
q = Foo.objects.values('created').distinct()
```

So far everything is great.

The problem is, if I have records created by a few seconds or milliseconds apart, I want to count them as one record.

So only queries created over a minute apart will be retrieved as two separate queries.
How to do it?
Thanks.

***EDIT:***
[Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) is a nice option, but didn't answer the question exactly.

Here's an example: If there are two records in `DB`, In the first record, the value in the `created` field is:

```
2020-02-23 12: 19: 59.000000
```

And in the second:

```
2020-02-23 12: 20: 01.000000
```

`Trunc` will retrieve two records, since they are two separate minutes.

but I want to retrieve only one record, because the time difference between the two records is less than a minute ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can truncate it to the resolution you need with Django [Trunc()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) function:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc    

Foo.objects.annotate(created_minute=Trunc('created','minute'))
     .values('created_minute').distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) database function with minute argument

```
Trunc('field', 'minute')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to those who answered.

I want to add, after reading the documentation following their answers, that `Django` has a built-in `Trunc` for different types of time units (new, days, hours, minutes, etc.)

For example:

`TruncMonth`, `TruncDay` , `TruncMinute`

so in my case, I could use [Elisha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62530891/9118235) answer:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
Foo.objects.annotate(created_minute=Trunc('created','minute'))
 .values('created_minute').distinct()
```

or I could just write:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMinute
Foo.objects.annotate(created_minute=TruncMinute('created'))
 .values('created_minute').distinct()
```

Another note: `Trunc` is a nice option, but didn't answer the question exactly.

Here's an example: If there are two records in `DB`, In the first record, the value in the `created` field is:

```
2020-02-23 12: 19: 59.000000
```

And in the second:

```
2020-02-23 12: 20: 01.000000
```

`Trunc` will retrieve two records, since they are two separate minutes.

but I want to retrieve only one record, because the time difference between the two records is less than a minute ..